# How to distribute a mdb file using an installer?

Tags: .net, database, ms-access

I have an Ms-Access file(.mdb).I want to distribute it as a software so that users may be able to use that without even having MS-Access.So basically i want to convert that .mdb file into .exe file which can be installed on clients maching.But i checked and i found out that it is not possible.For that we need to use some installer like Wise or InstallShield wizard.
Can this distribution be done using visual studio .net deployment package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I checked and found that it is not possible.

It is possible!  You can create the installer from MS Access 2010 which packages your .mdb file along with the [MS Access runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910).

*Edit*:  Here's a good link with instructions on [how to create the installer](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/access-2010-windows-installer-package-solution-wizard/).  It's quite straight-forward, and you could do it without the instructions; just click on the *Package Solution* option from the Access menu.

Comment: This is also possible in Access 2007 if you install the [Access Developer Extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24569)